# Web Part Feature and Reading XML File

Tags: sharepoint

I have deployed a custom Web Part as a Feature. I used STSDEV to create the Feature and supporting config files. I ran into some problems trying to add a simple XML file to contain values that I need to read. Where do I place the XML file within the Feature project and what do I need to do to access that file? After several attempts at this, my Web Part still renders but no longer appears in the list of Features to be activated via the browser interface... has anyone got any info on this? :-)

Comment: Could you post examples of your Xml files, thanks.

Comment: I eventually got this working and posted the solution here:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/01/25/Create-a-Web-Part-with-VSeWSS-13-Part-II.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that simple xml as configuraion for your webpart, then you can provide it as one of parameters in your *.webpart file. You will have to encode that file, this approach worked in our project at least.